# Is it possible to pass params to actions of MODX Revolution's manager in URL?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is it possible to pass parameters to actions of MODX Revolution's manager in a URL? If it is possible, how to do that? For example, I want to create a direct link to "System Settings" manager page and automatically open "core" namespace and "site" area.

Background:

There are some common sections on the site, which can be duplicated in several places. These sections are more like simple values, rather then blocks of code (let's say, phone numbers, address, some URLs, etc).

I know, that such functionality can be achieved with chunks, but it feels like it would be better to use custom system settings. At least, it would be great to keep end users out of site's templates, chunks, snippets, etc as long as it is possible. But it turned out that customers usually found such things pretty complicated, because it is hard to find them.

MODX Revolution allows developers to create custom widgets. Probably, it is possible to create a widget with a list of links to important areas for site administration. I successfully created an HTML widget with a link to system settings, but, unfortunately, I cannot construct a link to a specific area of them.

Probably, such things can be achieved with Custom  Manager Pages, but it looks like it is very hard to create them. I have not much experience with MODX API and never worked with ExtJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great extra for MODX Revolution called [ClientConfig](http://modx.com/extras/package/clientconfig), that could be used for managing those special system wide settings. Bonus: the access to all system settings could be denied for users with an editor role if ClientConfig is installed.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for pointing for this extra. Looks really great. And I even can create a link to this CMP on the dashboard. I've upvoted your answer, but I cannot accept it right now because it is a bit off topic in terms of an actual question. However, I'll accept it if nobody provides a more strict answer in a few days. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, the answer is somehow different, but since you told about the background of the question, it should be valid.